# Get property from string name using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am building a dynamic method, which takes in an object name (string)

```
 public Message Message => model;
```

What I need to do is get a particular property on Message using the name of the property like so:

```
Type myType = typeof("Message");
```

Then get the value of the property like this:

```
myType .GetProperty("Message").GetValue(myType, null);
```

"Message" will any string input which points to a property on the Message objecy

Is this possible using reflection?

Comment: `model.GetType()` or `typeof(Message)`?

Comment: @CodeCaster - whichever works

Comment: No, I mean it is unclear what you're asking. `typeof("Message")` won't compile, so what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I need to cast "Message" to the property in the class.

Comment: Message is the name of the property

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question so it shows a clear example.